# ¿Variables de sesión con distinto valor?

Tags: php, variables, sesiones

¿Por qué `$precio[$i]` de la *línea 21* no es un `float` si en la *linea* 4  he hecho un casting forzándolo?

He hecho varios `var_dump` intentando ver qué sucede pero sigo sin entenderlo.

Código:

```
$importeTotal = 0;
$cantidad = (float)($_SESSION['cantidad']);
$precio = (float)($_SESSION['precio']);
var_dump($_SESSION['precio'])."<br>";
var_dump((float)($_SESSION['precio']));
var_dump($precio);

$can=0;
$verPedido = "";
for ($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
    //$can = $cantidad[$i] * $precio[$i];
    //var_dump($can); 
    $verPedido +=  "Nombre Producto: ".$_SESSION['nombre_producto'][$i]."<br>
                   Cantidad: ".$cantidad[$i]."<br>
                    Precio: " .$precio[$i]."<br>
                    Importe: " .$precio[$i]*$cantidad[$i]."
    --------------------------------------------------------------------";
    //var_dump($precio[$i]); 
    //var_dump($can); 
    var_dump($precio[$i]);
    var_dump($_SESSION['precio'][$i]);
    $importeTotal += $precio[$i]*$cantidad[$i];
}
$verPedido += "Importe Total: $importeTotal";
//var_dump($_SESSION['cantidad']);
//echo "<div>$verPedido</div>";
```

> `array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "2.2" } float(1) float(1)`
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
>   in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto 1er Trimestre\php\vistas\confirmarVista.php** on *line 17*
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
>   in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto 1er Trimestre\php\vistas\confirmarVista.php** on *line 17*
>   `NULL string(3) "2.2"`
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
>   in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto 1er
>   Trimestre\php\vistas\confirmarVista.php** on *line 25*

Comment: Cuando le haces `var_dump()` a dichas variables que resultado obtienes en pantalla?

Comment: Lo he escrito en el post debajo del codigo 1ºarray(1) { [0]=> string(3) "2.2" } 2º float(1)  3º float(1) 4º NULL 5º string(3) "2.2"

Comment: Por lo que se puede deducir del código, $_SESSION['precio'] y $_SESSION['cantidad'] son arreglos. El problema muy seguramente está en que el hacer casting de un arreglo no da el resultado que esperarías. Si casteas un arreglo a float solo te dará 0 si está vacío o 1 si tiene algo dentro.

Comment: Tendrías que hacer el casting por cada elemento para lograr lo que intentas.

Comment: Estas haciendo casting al array, no a cada valor del arreglo. Dentro del `for` es una opción para hacerlo.